# Javascript promise execution time

Tags: javascript, promise

I have JS function which basically periodicaly call server and try if it's still online, I would like to show execution time of this function (something like "ping")

```
function preventOfflinePayment() {

            new Model('orgis.eet').call("pos_check_server_connection",{},undefined, {
                shadow: false,
                timeout: 2000
            })
                .done(function () {
                    $(".next").show();
                    $("#eet-status").css('color', 'limegreen');
                    $("#ping").html("Time: " + something);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    $(".next").hide();
                    $("#eet-status").css('color', 'red');

                });

            _.delay(function () {
                preventOfflinePayment();
            }, 1000);
        }
```

I dont know if it's possible to calculate this or not. Can you suggest something?

Comment: You could take a timestamp with MomentJS in milliseconds or microseconds before calling `new Model ...`, then take another on in done and fail, and check for the difference in time.

Comment: I don't think you can properly calculate how long will it take to contact server. You may still show notification, that you are updating status, without showing when it will end. You can still set `timeout` parameter in jQuery Ajax to set max execution time.

Comment: see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lj6rbkfs/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
function preventOfflinePayment() {
    var start = Date.now();
    var stop;
    new Model('orgis.eet').call("pos_check_server_connection",{},undefined, {
        shadow: false,
        timeout: 2000
    })
    .done(function () {
        stop = Date.now();
        var timeout = (stop - start) / 1000; // in ms
        $(".next").show();
        $("#eet-status").css('color', 'limegreen');
        $("#ping").html("Time: " + timeout + ' ms');
     })
     .fail(function () {
        stop = Date.now();
        var timeout = (stop - start) / 1000; // in ms
        $(".next").hide();
        $("#eet-status").css('color', 'red');
        console.log(timeout)
     });

     _.delay(function () {
       preventOfflinePayment();
     }, 1000);
}
```